# Calculating amount of frames based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a service that starts a computational task based on the users input. I'm at a stage where the user can input the frames they want to have computed, but I need a way to calculate the total amount of frames based on their input.

The input can look like the following: `eg.: "1-4; 10-20,2" will render frames 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20.`
and that would create the output `10`

```
So `;` is like a separator
x - y is from frame x to frame y
x - y , z is every z frame between frame x and frame y
```

I'm not sure where to start researching to create this function/algorithm (I hope thats the right word). Anyone who could point me in some kind of direction or help out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What part of the problem is giving you trouble: parsing the string or doing the math?

Comment: @user3386109 I know how to calculate it in my head, but not how to write the code to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple implementation in Javascript. No input validation and very basic / hardcoded logic. but it can be useful as a starting point.

First the input string is splitted on ";" and then each part is processed separately.

```
var input = "1-4; 10-20,2"
var totFrames = 0;

var chunk = input.split(";")
chunk.forEach(processChunk);

console.log(totFrames);

function processChunk(chunk) {
  var stepInfo = chunk.split(",");
  var step = 1;
  if(stepInfo.length > 1)
    step = stepInfo[1];

  var range = stepInfo[0].split("-");
  var frame = Math.round((range[1]- range[0]+ 1) / step);
  totFrames += frame;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I'm running a webapp so calculating it in the javascript on the page can also be done. Thanks! Merry christmast